# How to get the sum of total for each category in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel document which has 14 rows. I need to calculate total per each category using VBA.

[image]

I have attached dummy data. I need to find the total of Approx_Fees_in_USD for each distinct value in the column workstream i.e Total Approx_fees_in_USD for indirect tax,Direct tax, Statutory reporting etc using VBA.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is the modified code.

```
Public Sub summary()
 

  Dim sh As Worksheet, dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim lastRow As Long, arr As Variant, i As Long, key As Variant
  
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N:N").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B")
  Range("D1").Value = "Workstream"
  Range("E1").Value = "Total Fees per Workstream"
   
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
  Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Add key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=arr(i, 11) 'Subscript out of range
    Else
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 11)
    End If
  Next i
  i = 2
  For Each key In dict
    sh.Range("D" & i).Value = key
    sh.Range("E" & i).Value = dict(key)
    i = i + 1
  Next
  
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Get a unique list of values in the Workstream - either using `=UNIQUE(D2:D11)` in Excel 365, copy/paste and remove duplicates in Excel 2007+, or advanced filter in Excel 2003.  With a unique list you can then use this formula `=SUMIF($D$2:$D$11,$D14,$N$2:$N$11)`.

Comment: VBA? Seems like a task for Pivottables.

Comment: @JvdV I always forget about Pivot tables.  Much easier. :)

Comment: It can also be done (in VBA) using a Dictionary. I posted an answer using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It returns the result in columns "O:P".

It needs a reference to `'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'`. If you do not know how to add such a reference, I will show you. If you prefer without a reference, I will adapt the code to work without it:

```
Sub TotalPerCategory()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim lastRow As Long, arr As Variant, i As Long, key As Variant
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dict.aDD key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=arr(i, 2)
    Else
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
    End If
  Next i
  i = 2
  For Each key In dict
     sh.Range("C" & i).Value = key
     sh.Range("D" & i).Value = dict(key)
     i = i + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

In order to avoid the reference, please delete/comment the line:

```
'Dim sh As Worksheet, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

and use:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Edited: I adapted the code to process the range `"A2:N" & lastRow` as you requested.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, thank it is working for the same sheet. However I want to copy those columns into a new sheet and do the calculation there. I modified your code a bit and Im getting a subscript out of range error. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @the_new_guy: Yes, but how could I do that without seeing what you have done...? I will adapt the code in order to drop the data in another sheet. In a way to be easily adapted...

Comment: Yes, I know. Im not able to paste the code here. The code is too long.

Comment: @the_new_guy: Did it. It will return in another sheet, on columns A:B. Please, only replace "Your new sheet" with the real sheet name.

Comment: @the_new_guy: Not necessarily to paste the whole code! If it is only a matter of pasting in another sheet, I adapted it in a way to be easily adapted to your need. But I have a question: An important one, for my side: **Did you test the code as it is**?

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you please check that? As it is, your code works fine. I made some minor changes as now im getting that error.

Comment: What `.Cells(1, 4) = "Workstream"` does mean? any code line starting with a dot without being inside a `With object .... End With` does not make sense. Don't you receive an error on this line?

Comment: @the_new_guy: And where is your attempt to drop the data in another sheet?

Comment: I apologize for that. I have changed that. I have used range there.

Comment: There is no data in another sheet. Should I drop that?

Comment: Which "another sheet"? What " I want to copy those columns into a new sheet and do the calculation there" from your comment does mean? I have just adjusted the code to give you this possibility.  Only by changing of "Your new sheet" with the real sheet name...

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the code I posted?

Comment: Okay, so basically. All the data is in "Sheet1". I want to copy two columns i.e "Workstream" and "Approx_Fees_in_USD" into "Sheet2" and find the total for each workstream. This is where I have used your code.

Comment: But, if you copied the columns in different places, all the code is messed up. I am afraid that you do not understand anything from the above code... In my code the range D2:N lastRow is processed. How do you imagine that the code will work for A:N columns without being adapted to the real situation? In order to avoid wasting time, would you like me to make it working for columns A:N in the Sheet 2? If yes, where to return the processing result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216563/discussion-between-the-new-guy-and-faneduru).

Comment: You must adapt the array column where from the values are collected (Item:=arr(i, 11) to be replaced with Item:=arr(i, 14)). Column N:N starting from A:A is 14 not 11...